# One interface multipe implementations. How get the right one at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, solid-principles

Lets say I have an Object with one boolean field.

```
public class AnyPojo {
    private boolean b;
}
```

An interface DoAnything

```
public interface DoAnything {
   void doAnything();
}
```

And two `@Service` annotated implementations of DoAnything

```
public class DoAnythingOneImpl implements DoAnything {
   @Override
   public void doAnything(){
      //..
   }
}
public class DoAnythingTwoImpl implements DoAnything {
   @Override
   public void doAnything(){
      //..
   }
}
```

In another `@Service` class the boolean field of `AnyPojo` determines which implementation of `DoAnything` should be called. How can I achive that? I can use `ApplicationContext` here and make the decision like below. But not sure if there are better ways.

```
@Service
public class AnotherServiceImpl implements AnotherService {

    @Autowire
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void anotherDoing(AnyPojo anyPojo) {
       if(anyPojo.getB()){
          context.getBean(DoAnythingOneImpl.class).doAnything();
       } else{
          context.getBean(DoAnythingTwoImpl.class).doAnything();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that I would not call a service component from another service component to make sure I avoid potential redundant cycle in the future.
I would keep the following flow :

> Controller ---canCall---> Services ---canCall---> Repositories

And if you need services with a more complex logic, then introduces the concept of `Facade`

> Controller ---canCall---> Facades ---canCall---> Services ---canCall---> Repositories

However, here is a solution :

```
@Service("myServiceOne")
public class DoAnythingOneImpl implements DoAnything {
   @Override
   public void doAnything(){
      //..
   }
}
@Service("myServiceTwo")
public class DoAnythingTwoImpl implements DoAnything {
   @Override
   public void doAnything(){
      //..
   }
}
```

You can autowire both services and choose the best one based on your boolean :

```
@Service
public class AnotherServiceImpl implements AnotherService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myServiceOne")
    private DoAnything serviceOne;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myServiceTwo")
    private DoAnything serviceTwo;

    @Override
    public void anotherDoing(AnyPojo anyPojo) {
       if(anyPojo){
          serviceOne.doAnything();
       } else{
          serviceTwo.doAnything();
       }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that I can autowire both to the class. But from architecture style is that a good way to implement the stuff?

Comment: Hard to say, depend what's the business logic.
Maybe "public void doAnything(boolean value)" would be enough...

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean with _would not call a service component from another service component_ ?

Comment: The action you perform in "AnotherServiceImpl " acts as a Controller or a Facade. In fact, I would always respect this chain : 

You can interpet the arrow as "can call"
Controller -> Service -> Repository

Then if you need more complex services, you can use "Facade"
Controller -> Facade -> Service -> Repository

In this way, you're sure that you'll always avoid this problematic scenario :
ServiceA autowire ServiceB and ServiceB autowire ServiceA

Answer (score 2):

First things first, if your class requires particular implementations, why don't you simply inject these classes?

If you have several implementations of an interface, you have to inform Spring framework which one you would like to inject into a class. You can distinguish implementations by their unique bean names:

```
@Service("oneImpl")
public class DoAnythingOneImpl implements DoAnything {
   @Override
   public void doAnything(){
      //..
   }
}

@Service("twoImpl")
public class DoAnythingTwoImpl implements DoAnything {
   @Override
   public void doAnything(){
      //..
   }
}
```

And then inject both instances to the client service by marking which implementation should by assign to particular fields:

```
@Service
public class AnotherServiceImpl implements AnotherService {

    @Autowire
    @Qualifier("oneImpl")
    private DoAnything doAnythingOneImpl;
    @Autowire
    @Qualifier("twoImpl")
    private DoAnything doAnythingTwoImpl;

    @Override
    public void anotherDoing(AnyPojo anyPojo) {
       if(anyPojo){
          doAnythingOneImpl.doAnything();
       } else{
          doAnythingTwoImpl.doAnything();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that I can autowire both to the class. But from architecture style is that a good way to implement the stuff?

Comment: It's not different to your example in the question. In both ways you are tied to specific implementations.

Comment: `AnotherServiceImpl` is tied to specific implementations so there is not much that can be altered. The interface is actually useless with the given code structure. 
The other way to tackle this relation is to move the `DoAnything` reference to `AnyPojo` and pass the right implementation based on the value of the `b` variable when a particular object is created. Then expose the reference from the `AnyPojo` class so that `AnotherServiceImpl` can call it. But still, at some point you have to choose the implementation of the `DoAnything` interface, that you want to pass, you can't avoid it.